# "Nothing to start" when trying to start Apache Solr

Tags: java, apache, solr, lucene

I have `Ubuntu 14.10` and now I want to install and try `Apache Solr`. First of all, I visited official `Apache Solr` page and downloaded a zip [archive](http://apache-mirror.rbc.ru/pub/apache/lucene/solr/5.2.1/). Then I unzipped it in one folder called `solr`, so that this manually created folder now contains these files:

```
contexts/
libs/
modules/
...
start.jar
```

Among those files I see `start.jar` and, so, following one of the tutorials I tried this command (inside this very folder):

```
$ java -jar start.jar
```

But, as a result, I have this error message: `WARNING. Nothing to start, exiting...`. I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to http://lucene.apache.org/solr/quickstart.html the command to start Solr 5.2.1 is

```
bin/solr start -e cloud -noprompt
```

The reference to start.jar is from an older tutorial to a start.jar in the examples folder.

Comment: awesome ..it works for me .. thanks for sharing the link

Answer (score 12):

Add `--module=http` parameter.

Like this: `$ java -jar start.jar --module=http`

`bin/solr` does exactly that, except it shows complete disrespect for `Linux Standard Base (LSB)`. I would not recommend to use it.